# Is there any configuration setting for caching query results in mongoid?

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid

I have a Shop model which has_and_belongs_to_many Cuisines. Here are the controller action and edit form.

app/controllers/shops_controller.rb

```
class ShopsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @shop = Shop.where(id: params[:id]).first
    @cuisines = Cuisine.asc(:name)
  end
end
```

app/views/shops/edit.html.haml

```
= simple_nested_form_for @shop do |f|
  .control-group
    .control-label
      = f.link_to_add 'Cuisine', :cuisines
    .controls
      = f.fields_for :cuisines do |cuisine|
        = cuisine.input :id, label: false, collection: @cuisines
        = link_to t_action(:remove)
```

The issue is that @cuisines is evaluated as many times as number of cuisines of the shop. It does not caches the query after executing it for first time.

After searching and trying different solutions to reduce queries, i could only find out that using any of the following will help.

```
@cuisines = Cuisine.asc(:name).to_a
```

or

```
@cuisines = Cuisine.asc(:name).entries
```

or

```
@cuisines = Cuisine.asc(:name).cache
```

Can someone suggest me any other option for doing something like auto-caching?

Comment: Update- Have also tried this:
render partial: 'cuisine_fields', locals: { f: f, cuisines: @cuisines }
Still no change in queries.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo caches the documents used by your queries and keeps them in a working set in RAM:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#what-is-the-working-set

Whereas if you want to cache result of specific queries you can do it yourself by creating a different collection (say cuisine_cache), and store your query result in it. For each look up, first look in cache, and if you don't find it there, do the actual query and store it in cache for next access. You may want to expire your cache as well, for which you can use TTL:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

You can set the TTL as 'x' minutes, and if data is accessed again, reset the TTL again to 'x' so that the document is deleted only if it hasn't been accessed for x minutes; or you could put a hard limit of 'y' if your data changes significantly after y minutes. Just sharing some approaches, and you will need to base actual implementation depending on your requirements.